# How to wrap a json object inside of a top level object in visual basic

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm trying to be nest multiple objects inside of a main object but I'm really unsure of how to, especially with adding new objects to the object inside of that object.

Heres what I have so far, a sub that gets when the user clicks a button and runs a proccess  of using the data the user inputed and then submits it into a json file.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Dim monsterName As String
        monsterName = TextBox2.Text
        TextBox2.Text = ""

        Dim monsterCB As Integer
        monsterCB = TextBox3.Text
        TextBox3.Text = ""

        Dim monsterType As String
        monsterType = ComboBox3.SelectedItem
        ComboBox3.Text = ""


        Dim Monster As New Monster

        Monster.MonsterName = monsterName
        Monster.MonsterCombatRating = monsterCB
        Monster.MonsterType = monsterType

        Dim output As String

        output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Monster)

        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Program Files (x86)\D&DLoot\data.json", True)
        file.WriteLine(output)
        file.Close()



    End Sub
```

I also have a class.vb which just includes the defined properties and me trying to use them as an array within the class but I just get the output below, although I'm sure thats how you're supposed to get them to nest inside of the array:

```
Friend Class Monster

    Dim Monsterdata = New String() {MonsterName, MonsterCombatRating, MonsterType}

    Public Property MonsterName As String
    Public Property MonsterCombatRating As Integer
    Public Property MonsterType As String

End Class
```

This outputs a new line of this within my json file:

```
{"MonsterName":"testing","MonsterCombatRating":2,"MonsterType":"Bad"}
{"MonsterName":"here is another test","MonsterCombatRating":12,"MonsterType":"Bad"}
```

Each submission will add a new line just like this but json requires 1 top level comment, so the idea would be to get something like this as an end result, minus the loot arrays as thats for another event:

```
    {"Monsterlootdata":[
      { "Monstername":"testmonster1", "Loot":[{"lootname":"test1", "dropchance":"20", "rarity":"common"}, {"lootname":"test2", "dropchace":"5", "rarity":"rare"}]},
      { "Monstername":"testmonster2","Loot":[{"lootname":"test1", "dropchance":"40", "rarity":"common"}, {"lootname":"test2", "dropchance":"10", "rarity":"uncommon"},{"lootname":"test3", "dropchance":"5", "rarity":"rare"}]},
      { "Monstername":"testmonster3", "loot":[{"lootname":"test1", "dropchance":"80", "rarity":"common"}]}
]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're wanting is an object that has a property that is a collection so that when you go to serialize the object, it creates the `{"property": []}` output you want.

Take for example, the end result you're wanting. It can be represented as the following Visual Basic .NET class:

```vb
Public Class MonsterLoot
    Public Property lootname As String
    Public Property dropchance As String ' this should probably be an integer or double, but the JSON is representing it as a string so I didn't make any changes
    Public Property rarity As String
End Class

Public Class Monster
    Public Property Monstername As String
    Public Property Loot As List(Of MonsterLoot)
End Class

Public Class RootObject
    Public Property Monsterlootdata As List(Of Monster)
End Class
```

You would create a new instance of the object by doing the following:

```vb
Dim root = New RootObject() With {
    .Monsterlootdata = New List(Of Monster)({
        New Monster() With {
            .Monstername = "testmonster1",
            .Loot = New List(Of MonsterLoot)({
                New MonsterLoot() With {
                    .lootname = "test1",
                    .dropchance = "20",
                    .rarity = "common"
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Then when you would go to serialize the object, you'd get the following JSON:

```js
{
  "Monsterlootdata": [
    {
      "Monstername": "testmonster1",
      "Loot": [
        {
          "lootname": "test1",
          "dropchance": "20",
          "rarity": "common"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ILuel1

Comment: This works perfectly and thank you very much as I understand how the class system works now with this. I was also quite confused on how you're supposed to nest a new item within that list. Messing around with the link I was only able to get it to write out a new line of the item, rather than create something like a new loot table within the monster. Rather than just a whole new object on a new line.